# Improper Use of Property?

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors, worksheet

Right now, my code keeps coming up with an error when I try to run it or test it with an "Invalid use of Property" message. When I run it, the program highlights  the line "Sub Update_Audit()"

In my code, I'm trying to manipulate data for an audit between 3 sheets in a workbook.The first block of my code is to paste the data of items I need to find for the audit from the original sheet onto the 3rd sheet by setting each row equal to the data of the original row in the first sheet. The second block is used to re-paste the data of found objects in the Audit to only have values rather then formulas.Then the code will iterate through the Audit list to check for the same values and delete those values on the list in the 3rd sheet. The 2nd sheet will have the list of found audit items being pasted in at the same time. The end result is 3 sheets, 1st being just the main list where all the data is collected, the 2nd being a list of found audit items, and the 3rd being left over items that need to be found at a later date.

```
Sub Update_Audit()
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim Aud_Tot As Integer
    i = 2
    Aud_Tot = Application.InputBox("How big is your audit", , , , , , , 1)
    k = 2
    Do While Cells(k, 24) <> ""
        Tab_Data = Range(Cells(k, 24), Cells(k, 44)).Value
        Worksheets(3).Activate
        Range(Cells(k, 1), Cells(k, 22)).Value = Tab_Data
        Worksheets(1).Activate
        k = k + 1
    Loop
    Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And Not IsError(Cells(i, 2).Value)
        Dataset = Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 22)).Value
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 22)).Value = Dataset
        Worksheets(2).Activate
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 22)).Value = Dataset
        Worksheets(1).Activate
        For j = 2 To Aud_Tot
            If CStr(Cells(j, 24).Value) = CStr(Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
                Worksheets(3).Activate
                Range(Cells(j, 1), (Cells(j, 22))).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
                Worksheets(1).Activate
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What line does your code error out on?  I just ran the code with fake data and it completed.

Comment: Your question is twofold - first, the "Invalid use of property" error needs to be addressed; you need to tell us which line is raising that error. Next, "maybe some ways to make my code more efficient" would be [codereview.se] territory, but only after you get your code to work as intended. Please [edit] your post to focus on the "invalid use of property" error, *and then* make a new question with the working code on Code Review.

Comment: quick tip: Start using `Option Explicit`

Comment: Not as quick tip: avoid `activate` and qualify your cells/ranges instead.

Comment: @tjb1 the code error out on the Sub Update_Audit() line, because of that, have no idea what the problem is

Comment: Seems to work on my side. Can you give some exemple data?